# Rails Tutorial (M. Hartl) Chapter 9 (9.2.1 : Requiring logged user) Error: undefined method `user_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On chapter 9.2 of Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, I'm getting this 2 errors on the rake test after i made the test for redirecting user when they try to edit or update a profile that isn't theirs :

```
ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2016-04-18 06:27:31 +0100]
 test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1460957251.39s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x00564114110958>
            test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2016-04-18 06:27:31 +0100]
 test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1460957251.40s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x00564114035628>
            test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

The errors messages points to line 24 in my test_helper and line 28,36 in my users_controller_test :

```
test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/test_helper.rb:24:in `log_in_as'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

test_helper.rb :

Line 18 would be at *"remember_me"* in the **"log_in_as"** method.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical
  # order.
  fixtures :all
  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end
  # Log in a test user
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password] || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
        post login_path, session: {email: user.email,
                                                             password: password,
                                                             remember_me: remember_me}
    else
        session[:user_id] = user.user_id
    end
  end

  # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

user_controller_test.rb :

Line 28 would be at *"log_in_as(@other_user)"* in  **test "should redirect update when not logged in"**  and 36 at *"log_in_as(@other_user)"* in **test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user".**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user       = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end


  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

and this is the fixture file where :archer and :michael are stored(test/fixtures/users.yml):

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else
    session[:user_id] = user.user_id
end
```

There's no such attribute as `user_id`, you want...

```
else
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```